# ts-loader outputs declaration files in subdirectory when importing .json files

Tags: json, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm having a strange behavior of my ts-loader: When importing *.json file from node_modules the declaration files are generated in a subfolder of `dist/` but I expect them to be directly in the  `dist/` folder.

I have following project structure:

```
Project/
├── src/ 
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── PhoneNumberInput/
│   │       ├── index.ts
│   │       └── utils.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

When running `webpack` (using the `ts-loader`) I expect following output folder structure:

```
Project/
├── dist/ 
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── PhoneNumberInput/
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       └── utils.d.ts
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
└── ...
```

This was the case until I start importing a .json (from `node_modules/`) file within my `utils.ts`:

```js
import * as de from "react-phone-number-input/locale/de.json";
```

The declaration files are now generated under `dist/src/`:

```
Project/
├── dist/ 
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── components/
│   │   │   └── PhoneNumberInput/
│   │   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │   │       └── utils.d.ts
│   │   └── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
└── ...
```

Any relative imports to assets are now broken.
If I use the `awesome-typescript-loader` or import a .json from the project

```js
import * as de from "./countries.json";
```

I don't get the `src/` subfolder.

Does anyone have an idea where the behavior comes from? What I'm doing wrong? Or is it maybe a bug in the `ts-loader`?
The example project can be found at https://github.com/psalchow/ts-path-test

Here are the relevant config files:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "ts-path-test",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode=production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es2019"
  },
  "files": ["src/index.ts"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.ts',
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      library: 'DummyComponent',
      umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          // loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I had a closer look at the versions of the ts-loader. With 7.0.2 everything works as expected. Since 7.0.3 I get the behavior described above

Comment: hi, I had  some problem,  do you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question hasn't been touched for a long time.
With the current version (9.4.3) of `ts-loader` this problem does not occur anymore and everything is generated as expected directly under the `dist` folder (without any `src` subfolder). The test repo has been updated accordingly: https://github.com/psalchow/ts-path-test